# Converting a number to a date

Tags: sql, oracle, type-conversion

I have a calculation where I subtract two date values from each other. I receive a decimal value which I multiply with 60 (seconds), 60 (minutes), 24 (hours).
This value gives me the amount of seconds a specific ID spends in the system.

But I want to have the result of this calculation again in a date value, so I can work with date values in my design program.

```
select to_date((t2.time_event - t1.time_event) * 24 * 60 * 60,'hh24:mm:ss') as "Throughput_Time", count(t1.) as "Payments"
    from TBL_DUMMYFEED t1 
    join TBL_DUMMYFEED t2 on t1.trax_id = t2.trax_id
    where t1.event = 'created' and t2.event = 'sent'
    group by to_date((t2.time_event - t1.time_event) * 24 * 60 * 60,'hh24:mm:ss')
    order by to_date((t2.time_event - t1.time_event) * 24 * 60 * 60,'hh24:mm:ss');
```

I'm stuck because I can't get things right.

Comment: What would that date represent - how would you be able to use it later? You could add it to an arbitrary date but then you have to base all your later logic on that date too. If you want the number as a datetime type, maybe you want an interval instead?

Comment: A certain ID passes through different event states in my program.
To calculate the time it has been in the system I substract the date value from the first event state from the date value from the last event state. I use Logi Analytics to draw graphs with the data. But my query needs to return date values to use date formats on my axis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems very unwieldy, but if your really have to convert to a date datatype then you can add the date difference to another arbitrary date:

```
select date '1970-01-01' + (t2.time_event - t1.time_event) as ...
```

The fixed date can be anything, so I've just picked the Unix epoch.

Quick demo:

```
alter session set nls_date_format = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS';

with TBL_DUMMYFEED as (
  select 1 as trax_id, 'created' as event,
    to_date('2015-02-25 06:49:15', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') as time_event
  from dual
  union all
    select 1 as trax_id, 'sent' as event,
    to_date('2015-02-25 08:13:47', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') as time_event
  from dual
)
select t2.time_event - t1.time_event as raw_diff,
   (t2.time_event - t1.time_event) * 24 * 60 * 60 as diff_in_seconds,
   numtodsinterval(t2.time_event - t1.time_event, 'DAY') as diff_interval,
   date '1970-01-01' + (t2.time_event - t1.time_event) as fake_date
from TBL_DUMMYFEED t1 
join TBL_DUMMYFEED t2 on t1.trax_id = t2.trax_id
where t1.event = 'created'
and t2.event = 'sent';

   RAW_DIFF DIFF_IN_SECONDS DIFF_INTERVAL FAKE_DATE          
----------- --------------- ------------- -------------------
.0587037037            5072 0 1:24:32.0   1970-01-01 01:24:32
```

Sticking to a raw number or using an interval data type is neater but doesn't seem to fit into your design constraints.

Comment: It seems a little bit ugly but it works at least. Thanks for the help